# What design pattern to use for instantited objects containing permutations of a string?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, permutation

I would like to know if there is a design pattern to cover making multiple objects representing mutiple permutations of a string. For example:

I have a database table containing item names.
Each item has a sort of "signature" (can't think of a better word for it), which is all the letters of the item name, sorted in alphabetical order with the spaces removed.

Given a "soup string" of jumbled up letters, I would like to sort those letters in alphabetical order to match it to a signature in the database, but here's the catch...

Each soup string may contain a few extra letters. So what I'm looking for is a design pattern which would be suitable for taking a string and returning a list of objects, each representing a permutation of that soup string, which I can then fire at the database.

I was thinking about just using a factory, but isn't this outside of the scope of a factory? It does contain logic, (am I right in saying this is not business logic?), but perhaps this is acceptable for a factory or factory method? Then again, perhaps this is an perfect usecase for a factory.

Ultimately, I will probably just go with the factory method. I just wanted to see if there was a better option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds like applicative functors might be helpful. Can you share some examples of the kind of input and output you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with an object-oriented way of creating n objects from a given item. First, let's assume that the item is of type `String`; you can create a class `Permutations` which implements the interface `Iterable<String>` (basically, an object that acts as a list of elements of type `String`)

```kotlin
data class Permutations(val strings: Iterable<String>): Iterable<String> {
    
    constructor(string: String): this(...) {
        # transform string to permutations here (bonus: with lazy computations)
    } 
    
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<String> = strings.iterator()
}
```

Now, any object of type `Permutations` can replace a list of type `String`. Note that this class has two constructors, one takes a list of strings (the primary basic constructor) and one takes just one string and transforms it. This is not a design pattern; it's just a nice way to write objects out of objects without using static methods on util classes.

You can encapsulate the computation that transforms your string into permutations in (1) a different object (such as a strategy class), (2) a lambda function or (3) write our logic into the constructor (not recommended). The way you encapsulate the computation depends on how much flexibility you need.  :)

Edit: Small improvement for the primary constructor.